# Operation with Cartensian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I need to show the following using logical connectives:

$A\times (B\setminus C) =(A\times B)\setminus(A \times C)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(A\setminus B) \times C$ instead of $(A\times B \setminus C)$?

Comment: @dietervdf yes and no, it's suppose to be A x (B\C). Do you have a solution to it?

Comment: It doesn't seem te be true... 

Let $A=\{ 1\}, B= \{2,3\}, C=\{ 3\}$ then $A\times (B\setminus C) = \{(1,2)\}$ while $(A\times C) \setminus (B\times C) = \{ (1,3)\}\setminus\{ (2,3),(3,3)\} = \{ (1,3)\}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @dietervdf You are right again, hehe. Clumsy me :p, I've edited the post to the right one now.

Comment: ChuckP what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A \times B) \setminus (A \times C)= \{(x,y):(x \in A \land y \in B) \land (\overline{x \in A \land y \in C})\}= \{(x,y): (x \in A \land y \in B) \land (x \notin A \lor y \notin C) \} $
After distributing, $x \in A \land y \in B \land x \notin A$ is canceled, remains:
$=\{(x,y): x \in A \land (y \in B \land y \notin C) \}= \{(x,y):x \in A \land y \in B \setminus C \}=A\times(B\setminus C) $

Comment: That's a nice way to prove it. Cool!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I tried to go from A x (B\C) but this other way around seem to work out way better. thanks.

Comment: @ChuckP Heuristic: It is (almost) always easier to simplify then to introduce complexity, since there are many ways to introduce complexity, but few ways to simplify.  And therefore it is (almost) always easier to start at the most complex side of an equality.

Answer (score 2):

#### Just for fun

A nice geometrical <s>proof</s> way of looking at it ;)

[image: Proof using geometry]

Comment: That's not a proof. It only deals with the case that $B\cap C$ is non-empty, and $C$ is not a subset of $B$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila true, i guess 'way of looking at it' instead of 'proof' would be a better statement :)

Comment: A _very_ nice way of looking at the problem.  
What software did you use to make this?

Comment: @ZakariaDza: I just used some $\LaTeX$ tikzcode.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it using the following method:

1. Does $A\times (B\setminus C) \subseteq (A\times B) \setminus (A\times C)$?

   Let $(\alpha, \beta) \in A\times (B\setminus C)$ *(what does this mean?)*

   Then prove $(\alpha, \beta) \in (A\times B)\setminus (A\times C)$
2. Does $(A\times B) \setminus (A\times C) \subseteq A\times (B\setminus C)$?

   Use an analog method...

This would prove equality.

Comment: is there a way to show this using iffs and other logical connectives though? The problem I'm having is not knowing how to operate cartesian products with logical connectives.

Comment: I would guess the logical connectives come into place when proving the parts. For example $(\alpha, \beta) \in A\times (B\setminus C) \Leftrightarrow \alpha \in A \wedge \beta \in B \wedge \beta \not \in C$...